# Updating health bar progress

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a game and I've got 2 variables one for Hull, and one for shield. As of now I have the bar's updating like: 102/1000

What I'm going to do is underneath the text have the bar increase/decrease visually on the canvas. I want it to be 1 pixel per 10 hull, so 1000 hull(max) would be 100%.

Should I use substring?

Anyway I know how to draw on the canvas I am just trying to work out the best way of doing this? Before I refresh and update the bar's il add an if statement, this is what I have so far, I'm just wondering should I do it like this? or should I round the numbers up to be more accurate?

```
if(Player1.PlayerShield == 1000)
{
   //colour full shield bar, take out last number

}


if(Player1.PlayerHull == 1000)
{

   //colour full hull bar, take out last number
}


if(Player1.PlayerShield == 3 digits)
{
  //take out last variable and draw, so 157 would draw 15%
}

else if(Player1.PlayerShield == 2 digits)
{
    //take out last variable and draw, so 17 would draw 10%
}

else if(Player1.PlayerShield == 1 digits)
{
  dont make any changes
}

else
{
draw fully transparent
}



if(Player1.PlayerHull == 3 digits)
{
  //same as shield
}

else if(Player1.PlayerHull == 2 digits)
{
   //same as shield
}

else if(Player1.PlayerHull == 1 digits)
{
  //same as shield
}

else
{
draw fully transparent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your helth bar have 150px, maxHealth is 300, current health is 150. you divide 300/150 = 2 and draw bar 150 / 2 = 75px. so, if your health is 100, 300/100 = 3, draw bar 150 / 3 = 50px